# When do you use brace expansion?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I understood what [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) is.
But I don't know where I use that.

When do you use it?
Please give me some convenient examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range expression form of brace expansion is used in place of `seq` in a `for` loop:

```
for i in {1..100}
do
    something    # 100 times
done
```

Answer (score 2):

For example, make a backup of all your files in a directory:

```
for i in * ; do
    cp "$i"{,.bak}
done
```

Comment: Sorry, moved {,.bak} outside of the quoted part. was a typo.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. In fact, I didn't realise until now that the path components don't need to exist.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you use brace expansion if you want to create a range, eg

`for r in {0..100}`

`for r in {0..10..2}` #with step of 2

`for z  in {a..z}`

Instead of using external commands such as `seq 0 100`.
Also , brace expansion can be used to list file types, eg

`for file in *.{txt,jpg}`.

This list all files that has txt and jpg extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You use it whenever you want to match against multiple choices. E.g.,

```
ls src/{Debug,Release}/*.o  # List all .o files in the Debug and Release directories.
```